# GiftAid extension 3.1.0 compatible with CiviCRM 5.x?

Tags: wordpress, gift-aid-extension

I'm running WP 5.4 / CiviCRM 5.24.3 / php 7.3.16 / gift-aid-extension 3.1.0 / uk-hmrc-online-gift-aid-submission 1.7.3

Just going to do my first GiftAid submission (now that I have some donations to claim), and the extension isn't working - drops straight to the default admin console.

Looking at the extension info page, and civi-5.0 isn't listed for ver 3.1.0 (though it is listed for 3.0.4). It this a typo on their part, and a reinstall on mine, or did something break with 3.1.0?
https://civicrm.org/extensions/gift-aid-extension-uk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, version 3.1.0 of the Gift Aid extension (from Compucorp) certainly works with release 5.19.x and 5.24.x. As you've obviously upgraded fairly recently then try clearing caches?

Comment: ok - usually clear caches on upgrade, but will run again, and if still nothing will try an uninstall - reinstall, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Clearing caches (after upgrading to 5.24.5) did the trick, thanks.